# Deleting a node from the middle of a heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, dijkstra

Deleting a node from the middle of the heap can be done in O(lg n) provided we can find the element in the heap in constant time. Suppose the node of a heap contains id as its field. Now if we provide the id, how can we delete the node in O(lg n) time ?

One solution can be that we can have a address of a location in each node, where we maintain the index of the node in the heap. This array would be ordered by node ids. This requires additional array to be maintained though. Is there any other good method to achieve the same.

PS: I came across this problem while implementing Djikstra's Shortest Path algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index (id, node) can be maintained separately in a hashtable which has O(1) lookup complexity (on average). The overall complexity then remains O(log n).

Comment: Yeah this is one of the solutions. I think its not possible without using extra space. right?

Comment: A problem with this external hashcode idea is that in a normal heap, the items are always moving around in Heapify(), which will require a hashtable update, or delete/insert, for every swap.  That starts to get to a huge number of hash table updates, at which point some other log-n insert, log-n delete data structure would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Each data structure is designed with certain operations in mind. From wikipedia about heap operations

```
The operations commonly performed with a heap are:
create-heap: create an empty heap
find-max or find-min: find the maximum item of a max-heap or a minimum item of a min-heap, respectively
delete-max or delete-min: removing the root node of a max- or min-heap, respectively
increase-key or decrease-key: updating a key within a max- or min-heap, respectively
insert: adding a new key to the heap
merge joining two heaps to form a valid new heap containing all the elements of both.
```

This means, heap is not the best data structure for the operation you are looking for. I would advice you to look for a better suited data structure(depending on your requirements)..

Comment: Dijsktra algorithm requires deletion from the middle of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and here's what I've come up with:

**Solution 1:** if your calls to delete some random item will have a pointer to item, you can store your individual data items outside of the heap; have the heap be of *pointers* to these items; and have each item contain its current heap array index.

Example: the heap contains pointers to items with keys [2 10 5 11 12 6].  The item holding value 10 has a field called ArrayIndex = 1 (counting from 0).  So if I have a pointer to item 10 and want to delete it, I just look at its ArrayIndex and use that in the heap for a normal delete.  O(1) to find heap location, then usual O(log n) to delete it via recursive heapify.

**Solution 2:** If you only have the key field of the item you want to delete, not its address, try this.  Switch to a red-black tree, putting your payload data in the actual tree nodes.  This is also O( log n ) for insert and delete.  It can additionally find an item with a given key in O( log n ), which makes delete-by-key continue to be log n.

Between these, solution 1 will require an overhead of constantly updating ArrayIndex fields with every swap.  It also results in a kind of strange one-off data structure that the next code maintainer would need to study and understand.  I think solution 2 would be about as fast, and has the advantage that it's a well-understood algo.